# "Screen Display" in settings redundant?

Tags: gnome, display, screen, 20.04

[image]

are any other types of displays besides screen supported?
would they be in a different section of settings?

if not it seems redundant and like "Display" would be a better name for this setting?
but maybe that is just because i (noob) keep expecting display settings to be under display in menu

is that a question?
thanks

Comment: Is this unique to 20.04?

Comment: Nomeclature change is not something we can deal with here. You can suggest it to the developers concerned.

Comment: but if someone said there is a foo display that shows up when you plug in a bar it would 'answer the question' some sort of non-screen display